# Video Streaming and Load Testing Using Apache JMeter

Tags: xml, apache, video-streaming, jmeter, load-testing

I have made an HTTP Request to a webpage and it respond successfully with a VAST code (XML) Afterwards I used Apache JMeter Regular Expressions Extractor for Extracting a URL from the **MediaFile** tag in the responded XML code.

Here is the responded data (VAST XML):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<VAST version="2.0">
  <Ad id="brightroll_ad">
    <InLine>
      <AdSystem>BrightRoll</AdSystem>
      <AdTitle></AdTitle>
      <Impression><![CDATA[http://brxserv-22.btrll.com/v1/epix/6835714/3858435/84416/140363/AbQ93_XgMgCcRUTi_JAAFJwAACJEsAOuADAAAAAAAiyel-GCNFFg/event.imp/r_64.aHR0cDovL2Iuc2NvcmVjYXJkcmVzZWFyY2guY29tL3A_JmMxPTgmYzI9NjAwMDAwNiZjMz04NDQxNiZjND0zODU4NDM1JmM1PTIwNDYzJmM2PTY4MzU3MTQmYzEwPTE0MDM2MyZjdj0xLjcmY2o9MSZybj0xNDE0NDEwMTg1JnI9aHR0cCUzQSUyRiUyRnBpeGVsLnF1YW50c2VydmUuY29tJTJGcGl4ZWwlMkZwLWNiNkMwekZGN2RXakkuZ2lmJTNGbGFiZWxzJTNEcC42ODM1NzE0LjM4NTg0MzUuMCUyQ2EuMjA0NjMuODQ0MTYuMTQwMzYzJTJDdS45NjguNjQweDM2MCUzQm1lZGlhJTNEYWQlM0JyJTNEMTQxNDQxMDE4NQ]]></Impression>
  <Impression><![CDATA[http://rc.rlcdn.com/361686.gif]]></Impression>
  <Creatives>
    <Creative id="140363" sequence="1">
      <Linear>
        <Duration>00:00:30</Duration>
        <TrackingEvents>
          <Tracking event="midpoint"><![CDATA[http://brxserv-22.btrll.com/v1/epix/6835714/3858435/84416/140363/AbQ93_XgMgCcRUTi_JAAFJwAACJEsAOuADAAAAAAAiyel-GCNFFg/event.mid]]></Tracking>
          <Tracking event="complete"><![CDATA[http://brxserv-22.btrll.com/v1/epix/6835714/3858435/84416/140363/AbQ93_XgMgCcRUTi_JAAFJwAACJEsAOuADAAAAAAAiyel-GCNFFg/event.end]]></Tracking>
        </TrackingEvents>
        <AdParameters></AdParameters>
        <VideoClicks>
          <ClickTracking><![CDATA[http://brxserv-22.btrll.com/v1/epix/6835714/3858435/84416/140363/AbQ93_XgMgCcRUTi_JAAFJwAACJEsAOuADAAAAAAAiyel-GCNFFg/event.click]]></ClickTracking>
        </VideoClicks>
        <MediaFiles>
          <MediaFile type="application/x-shockwave-flash" apiFramework="VPAID" height="360" width="640" delivery="progressive">
            <![CDATA[http://brxcdn3.btrll.com/69325/Brand-display.flv]]>
          </MediaFile>
        </MediaFiles>
      </Linear>
    </Creative>
  </Creatives>
</InLine>
```

and Here is the URL which I have successfully extracted from this XML.

```
  http://brxcdn3.btrll.com/69325/Brand-display.flv
```

So Now I want to stream this video file using Apache JMeter. Knowing that this video could be shown to the same IP(User) only 3 times a day. Any Idea about how to stream and perform a load testing to a video through JMeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the current functionality, it is not possible to load test stream videos using Jmeter.

Comment: I have read some recommendations to use **JP@GC** for this case, but since it's an undocumented plugin , i can't get more information. Do you think it could help ?